# surface sdk scatterview

Tags: c#, kinect, multi-touch, pixelsense

I'm using bluetooth surface published in http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Surface-Bluetooth-Connect-dbe7e0e8 I add the kinect in this wpf application. But i need multitouch function to zoom in and zoom out the scatterviewitem picture. So can anyone give me idea about how can i achieve multitouch in this application.
And i also try using kinect gesture to zoomin the scatterview, but it still have a problem how to select the scatterviewitem in scatterview and zoom it.

I'm add all kinect function in MainWindow class, so how can i achieve all scatterviewitems in scatterview, and zoom I select one.

I'm using Win7, not touch screen.